# Cloudwatch parsing same field from array of objects/records in json in @message

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I am finding difficulty to extract all the same fields and it's values from objects where the objects are in
array(array of objects in json).

I tried with `|parse @message '"currency":"*"' as currencies`

but getting *only first match searched(a single first field)* and not all the searches(the matched field from all the objects) from json.

**Filter** command is used to extract the log/@message from log group.....but not the fields from single json log or @message.

Can anyone help me out here.

Example Json:

```
.......

......

....

"body":
     {

     "totalSize":4,

     "done":true,

     "records":[

          {"city":"london",

           "currency":"GBP",

           "Country":"GB"
           },
          {"city":"london,

           "currency":"USD",

           "Country":"GB"
          },
          {"city":"Monaco,

           "currency":"EUR",

           "Country":"MC"
          },        

          {"city":"london,

           "currency":"GBP",

           "Country":"GB"

          }
        ]
}
```

***Expected values:***

currencies

GBP,USD,EUR,GBP

***Actual values:***

currencies

GBP

Getting only first value from message log

I tried

```
|Parse @message /\"currency\":\"(?<currencies>.*?)\"/
```

Or

```
|Parse @message /\"(?<field>currency)\":\"(?<currencies>.*?)\"/
```

What I tried

```
fields @message
|filter @message like 'totalSize'
|Parse @message /\"currency\":\"(?<currencies>.*?)\"/
|display currencies
```